# Is there anyway I could retrieve the data of all the films that have the same name but different scores?

Tags: java, list, nio

When I run the program and choose to search by score, the same title is printed for the same score instead of printing the other titles

```
  private void searchReviewScore() throws IOException {
    int review = getNumberInput(_scanner, 1, 5, "Enter minimum rating (1 - 5): ");

    // Get the list of scores from the file.
    Path path = Paths.get("scores.txt");
    List<String> allScores = Files.readAllLines(path);

    for (String movieScore : allScores) 
    {
        int movieScoreInt = Integer.parseInt(movieScore);
        if (review <= movieScoreInt) { 
            int i = allScores.indexOf(movieScore);
            presentMovieAndScore(i);
        }
    }
    //TODO: Add call to search movie database based on input

    //TODO: Present results to user

}
```

Here is my Print method.

```
/**
 * @param i
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void presentMovieAndScore(int i) throws IOException {
    Path movies = Paths.get("movies.txt");
    List<String> allMovies = Files.readAllLines(movies);

    Path path = Paths.get("scores.txt");
    List<String> allScores = Files.readAllLines(path);

    System.out.println("Titel: " + allMovies.get(i) + " rating: " + allScores.get(i));
}
```

Here is the content of movie.txt `bones matrix deceptions suits bones Gladiator`

the score.txt contains: `1 2 5 3 4 1`

Comment: Can you add the content of movies.txt and scores.txt files to the question?

Comment: So for the given data you would want to see `bones` and `1,4`?

Comment: @WJS I'm already getting bones and 1, 4. The problem is that all other movies that have  the same rating but different name are getting changed into bones as well.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your problem is with this line of code :

> int i = allScores.indexOf(movieScore);

indexOf method returns always first match.
So if your table has same value twice in different positions in table example at 1 and 5 ,it will allways return 1.In this case ,since you want the position of the element using  for each loop is not good idea ,try to use index for loop.

```
private void searchReviewScore() throws IOException {
int review = getNumberInput(_scanner, 1, 5, "Enter minimum rating (1 - 5): ");

// Get the list of scores from the file.
Path path = Paths.get("scores.txt");
List<String> allScores = Files.readAllLines(path);

for ( int i=0; i<allScores.size() ;i++) 
{   
    String movieScore =allScores.get(i);
    int movieScoreInt = Integer.parseInt(movieScore);
    if (review <= movieScoreInt) { 
        presentMovieAndScore(i);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are chosing the first name for a given score.  So when you see 1, you use that to index into your movies and get `bones` when you really want `gladiator`. I recommend puting them in a `TreeMap<Integer,List<String>>` where the `key` is the `score` and the `value` is a `list of movies` of that score.

Another possibility would be to create a `Movie` class and store the name and score in the class. That would also be beneficial if you ever want include more information about the movie.

A `TreeMap` offers some advantages as demostrated below.

The `TreeMap` lets you chose `subMaps` base on ranges of the keys.  How you populate that map is up to you.  You can also choose explicit scores for a list of movies at that rating.

```
Scanner readMovies = null;
Scanner readScores = null;
try {
readMovies = new Scanner(new File("f:/movies.txt"));
readScores = new Scanner(new File("f:/scores.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
    fne.printStackTrace();
}
// read in the values.
// The key is the score.
// the value is a list of movies that have that score.

TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> data = new TreeMap<>();
while (readMovies.hasNext()) {
    data.computeIfAbsent(readScores.nextInt(),
            k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(readMovies.next());
}

//prompt for rating

int minRating = 1;
int maxRating =  3;
// Now as an example, get a list of movies in the range
// of the ratings that exist in the map.
Map<Integer,List<String>> subMap = data.subMap(data.ceilingKey(minRating),
        data.floorKey(maxRating));
// And print them out.
subMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

In this case this prints.

```
1=[bones, Gladiator]
2=[matrix]
```

Since there are no ratings of 3, it stopped at 2.

Comment: I modified my answer to explain the problem you were having.  There was nothing wrong with your idea, just an implementaton gltich.  I think a map would be a better choice.  How you employ it is up to you.  Note also, that in your presentMovie method you read the files each time.  In the future it is best to read them in once and then just reference them.